# For any integers $x$, $n$ greater than 1, there exists a positive integer $y$ such that $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Question: Prove or disprove the statement: "For any integers $x$, $n$ greater than 1, there exists a positive integer $y$ such that $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$."

Proof: Let $y \equiv -x \pmod{n}$. Then $y = kn - x$ for some integer $k$. Substituting this into $x + y$, we have:

$$x+y=x+(kn−x)=kn\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

Thus, there exists a positive integer $y$ (namely $y \equiv -x \pmod{n}$) such that $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$. Therefore, the statement is true.

I am unsure if this is correct or on the right track. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You would need to say something about why you can say there exist a *positive* y satisfying the condition.